# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in simple c++ XCODE program

Tags: c++, xcode, exc-bad-access

I'm new to c++ and I'm trying to make a calculator. I designed this function for the purpose of getting factorial of a number:

```
     int factorial(int num1) {
    int sum;
    if (num1 == 1) {
        sum = 1;
    }
    else {
        sum = factorial((num1 - 1) * num1);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Whenever I try and compile this, however, I get the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the

```
int factorial(int num1)
```

Any idea what's going on? I'm using XCODE.

Comment: I doubt the compiler crashes, instead I think it's your program that crashes when you attempt to run it. But we can't really say much unless we have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please edit your question to include that, most importantly how you *call* the function (not declare it). And if you read input then also include the actual input you give. Or try to solve it yourself by running your program in the debugger.

Comment: However, if you pass e.g. `2` into the function you will have *infinite recursion*. You can use a debugger to find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition leads to an infinite recursion whenever `num1` is not `1`.

Do the maths yourself:

```
  factorial(2)
= factorial((2-1) * 2)
= factorial(2)
= factorial((2-1) * 2)
= ...
```

or

```
  factorial(3)
= factorial((3-1) * 3)
= factorial(6)
= factorial((6-1) * 6)
= factorial(30)
= ...
```

The recursive definition of the factorial function is not

```
factorial(n) = factorial((n - 1) * n)
```

it is

```
factorial(n) = n * factorial(n - 1)
```

(And the factorial is not a sum, but a product.)